# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User without an ID) при работе с ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Хочу осуществить оправку писем в приложении на RoR. Для этого использую такой код в app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:

```
 class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'notifications@example.com'

  def welcome_email
    @inheritor = User.find(params[:inheritor_id])
    @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
    mail(to: @inheritor.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
end
```

В контроллере в экшене `create`:

```
UserMailer.with(inheritor: @inheritor).welcome_email.deliver_later
```

В app/models/user.rb:

```
has_many :inherited_accounts, class_name: 'AccountTransfer', foreign_key: 'inheritor_id'
```

Но при вызове экшена `create` в консоле выдает ошибку "Couldn't find User without an ID"

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Вы вызываете мэйлер через:

```
UserMailer.with(inheritor: @inheritor).welcome_email.deliver_later
```

Значит, в параметрах мэйлера у вас будет ключ `inheritor`, вы же пытаетесь использовать ключ `inheritor_id`. Исправьте на

```
@inheritor = params[:inheritor]
```

Вам даже искать пользователя не надо, вы ведь сразу сущность передаёте при вызове мэйлера

P.S. Вставляйте в вопрос полный лог ошибки, с указанием на конкретную строку, так гораздо проще дебажить